# How can I prevent a popup to show when clicking on a marker in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I want a popup that doesn't show itself when I click on the Leaflet marker. I cannot use `clickable : false` because it will make the markers "act as a part of the underlying map" and this is unacceptable for me. I tried the following code:

```
marker.on('click', function(event) {
  event.originalEvent.preventDefault();
});
```

without any results. What is the right way to prevent a popup from showing without using the `clickable : false` property of the marker object?

All I need is to open all the popups on the map by clicking on one custom button, but I don't want the popups to show themselves after I click on a particular marker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just don't bind a popup to the marker. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkeller3/d6oLn4as/) with 2 markers. One has a popup and the other does not.

```
L.marker([51, 0]).bindPopup("this is a popup").addTo(map);

L.marker([51, 1.5]).addTo(map);
```

**EDIT:**
I've edited the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkeller3/d6oLn4as/) and think it might be what you are asking. Here's the important part of the code:

```
function onClick(event) {
    event.target.closePopup();
}
```

Comment: I suppose that is not the case for me because I still need popups. All I need is to open all the popus on the map by clicking one custom button, still I don't want popup show itself after I click on the particular marker.

Comment: Just FYI, `event.target.closePopup();` does not work with the current version of leaflet. If you have access to the map as a global variable, you can do `map.closePopup();` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Try this workaround:

```
marker.bindPopup('my popup content');

// remove openPopup click handler (actually all click handlers)
marker.off('click');

// Do nothing on click. This is not necessary, but now marker
// doesn't act like part of underlying map
marker.on('click', function() {return;});
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SeMICxLuwvv46Ta5F8pH?p=preview) for details.

Answer (score 4):

None of the other answers worked for me (possibly because of a newer version of Leaflet). I ended up skipping `marker.bindPopup()` and just creating the popups separately using `L.popup()` then calling `map.openPopup(thePopup)` when I needed them to appear.

Something like this:

```
var map = L.map(),
    popup = L.popup().setContent("Stuff"),
    marker = L.marker();
popup.setLatLng(marker.getLatLng());

// In my event handler
map.openPopup(popup);
```

Answer (score 3):

Juste remove `openPopup` from the click event of the marker.

```
marker.bindPopup('My popup!');
marker.off('click', this.openPopup);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for me. although I had to use the "hidden" method `_openPopup` instead of the "public" `openPopup`, and the reference object should be `marker` instead of `this` .

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to remove the event listener yourself, you can just call [.unbindPopup()](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-unbindpopup) to remove the previously set popup as soon as the marker transitions to your "disabled" state:

```js
marker.bindPopup('My popup!');
marker.unbindPopup();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need to use handled  onClick Event use :

```
marker.off('click');
```

if you wnat to handel event and prevent popUp to show use :

```
.on('click', function (event) {
  try{
    event.preventDefault();
  }catch(err){}
});
```

Answer (score -2):

add return false . it should work. though i am not very sure.

```
marker.on('click', function(event) {
  event.originalEvent.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```