# How do I toggle clickable marker property using custom control in Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, maps, leaflet

As I can see Marker contains no methods to change clickable property (true/false). And I need to change this property  many times after the all markers was creating (I understand that I can create a new marker based on the old one, but this is really overhead and I'd like to avoid it) By this time I tried this method to handle onclick event on my custom button:

```
function makeMarkersClickable() {
  for (var id in myMarkers) {
    var marker = myMarkers[id];
    marker.options.clickable = true;
    marker.clickable = true;
  }
}
```

Obviously it didn't work. Seems that there should be a method to update the whole map or something like that to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to this issue:

- "I understand that I can create a new marker based on the old one, but this is really overhead and I'd like to avoid it": you would do this. This is the better solution, and you shouldn't prematurely optimize this. Non-settable options are that way for a reason.
- Set `clickable` to `true` all the time and [add and remove](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events-on) the event listener.

Comment: Just tried your second advice. After creating a marker with clickable: true; I used marker.off('click'); Now when I try to click on marker it shows me a popup. But that is completely unacceptable for me. Honestly I use clickable: false as a workaround to prevent popups showing by click on markers. Maybe you can help me with that, I have recently created a separate question for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638432/how-can-i-prevent-popup-showing-by-clik-on-marker-in-leaflet

Comment: Never mind I found all the answers I need. I checked my other question and I found the answer there and now I don't need to toggle popups anymore

Comment: By the way your second advice did work for me. I made a mistake first time but then I got it working

Comment: @tmcv, should I use the same startegy to toggle draggable ?